# tetration limit tending to 0

Tags: limits, tetration

Let $x \uparrow \uparrow  n = x^{x^{x^{x}}}$ ex: $x \uparrow \uparrow 3 = x^{x^x}$

I'm trying to evaluate the limit

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{3 \uparrow \uparrow \frac{1}{n} - 1 }{2 \uparrow \uparrow  \frac{1}{n} - 1 }$$

Obviously L'hopitals rule has some value here, but once applied i am stuck attempting to differentiate the tetration function and i'm not sure how to go about doing this.

This problem originates from attempting to find a homomorphism for exponentation. That is a complex function $g(x)$ such that $g(x^y) = g(x)^{g(y)}$

Comment: You defined $x  \uparrow \uparrow n$ for a natural $n$. What is meant by $3  \uparrow \uparrow  1/n$?

Comment: It is likely that a tetration of $1/n$ is referring to the $n$th [super root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Super-root), just like how a power of $1/n$ is the $n$th (regular) root.

Comment: @AidenChow If it does, it should be clarified. In fact the [very same page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Higher_order_approximations_for_real_heights) explains that the expression here cannot be the $n$th super root. Voting to close the question until this point is actually clarified.

Comment: i made a mistake, i meant to put a 1/n but it appears that i was too easily convinced that 1/n tetrate == super-root and then assumed i need to restate the question but accept the answer that was given below.

Answer (score 2):

If $a\uparrow\uparrow(1/n)$ means the $n$th superroot of $a$, usually rendered $\sqrt[n]a_s$, then for $a\ge 1$ there are two possible behaviors as $n\to\infty$:

- If $1\le a\le e$ there is a unique base $s$, with $1\le s\le\exp(1/e)$, for which $s\uparrow\uparrow n$ converges to the selected value of $a$, namely $s=a^{1/a}$.
- If $a>e$, then the superroot is always greater than $e^{1/e}$ but the tetrations of any fixed number greater than $e^{1/e}$ will blow up past the target value of $a$.  Therefore the $n$th superroot of $a$ is forced to converge to $e^{1/e}$ as $n\to\infty$.

So in the above example with $3>e$ but $2<e$, the limit is simply

$\dfrac{e^{1/e}-1}{\sqrt2-1}=(e^{1/e}-1)(\sqrt2+1)$.

Note that neither term of the fraction goes to zero because superroots do not in general converge to $1$.  Therefore the form is not indeterminate.

Comment: Hi clarification was made. I don’t mean super root but actually 1/n tetrate

Comment: So, we are back to the original question.  How is the $1/n$ tetrate defined?

Comment: I was thinking of defining it gamma function style. We can define $a \uparrow\uparrow 0 = 1$ to respect the functional equation $a \uparrow\uparrow (n+1) = a^{a \uparrow \uparrow n}$. Now we can make a definition of $a \uparrow\uparrow n$ for  $a \ge 1$ over the interval $[0,\infty)$.  We claim there should be a unique curve $[0, \infty) \rightarrow [1, \infty)$ which satisfies this functional equation on all points over the interval, and is convex (that is second derivative $\ge$  0 for all points over the interval), and is smooth ( derivatives of all orders exist at all points).

Comment: You may want to read the WP article on tetration, which includes some approaches to extension.  There are multiple approaches depending on the mathematical properties you want and even the domain you intend to consider.

Comment: "is convex (that is second derivative ≥ 0 for all points over the interval)".  You can't universally have this.  Of you tetrate $1.1$, you have $f(0)=1, f(1)=1.1, f(2)=1.1105..., f(3)=1.1116...$ which cannot have positive second derivative throughout (at least) $[0,3]$.